# How to render the same page component including getServerSideProps in different route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this folder structure:

```
/
 |- ...
 |- pages
     |- info
     |   |- main.tsx
     |- extra
         |- main.tsx
```

Both `/info/main` and `/extra/main` routes render the same content, including the `getServerSideProps`. My question is how to implement the logic in one of them and reuse it in the other, so the code is not duplicated. I tried in `extra/main.tsx`:

```
import MainCmp from '../info/main';
export default MainCmp;
```

and it works, but it doesn't execute `getServerSideProps`. Also tried with `rewrites`:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/extra/main',
        destination: '/info/main',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

and works again, but then the url is `/info/main` instead of `/extra/main` when loading some extra...

Any hint on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js expects a default export (used to render the page) and a named `getServerSideProps` export to call before rendering. You could do so:

```
//extra/main.tsx

import MainCmp from '../info/main';
export { getServerSideProps }  from '../info/main';
export default MainCmp;
```

You could also use a helper function to be called by the `getServerSideProps` of each page, and a component that gets the data and displays it to be called by each page component.

Answer (score 1):

Get something like this ready

[image: Slug]

Remove extra and info folders

Put your code inside main.tsx

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Slug = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <h1>Slug: {router.query.slug}</h1>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps = () => {
    console.log('Slug Page')
    return {
        props: {}
    }
}

export default Slug
```

Browse http://localhost:3000/extra/main (Prints Slug: extra)

Browse http://localhost:3000/info/main (Prints Slug: info)

All should be redirected to the same content with different outputs

Read more on https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes